# Esper - the 'or' keyword

Tags: java, comparison, complex-event-processing, esper

is there a shortcut to write the 'or' in esper just like sql?

for example if I have the following EPL: "select * from event(price = 2 or price = 4 or price = 184)" Is it possible to have something in really short like for example: "select * from event(price = 2/4/184)" ? I have tried the sql format, the coma, ect.. but nothing seems to work and writing explicitly becomes tedious if you have many values to compare to.  Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

EPL adheres to SQL standard and allows "price in (2, 4, 184)"